# How to tap unix socket

Tags: bash, networking, socat

I have app A and B and they are communicating using unix socket. What I need is to tap this socket and listen/send the communication for evaluation?

```
socat -t100 -x -v UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.sock,mode=777,reuseaddr,fork ,UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.sock_original
```

Works fine for dumping it into console, but how can I add like UDP-SENDTO?
And can I?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe this has been [asked before](http://superuser.com/questions/484671/can-i-monitor-a-local-unix-domain-socket-like-tcpdump).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the way. It's not optimal but working

```
socat -t100 -x -v UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/.sock,mode=777,reuseaddr,fork ,UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/.sock_original | 
awk '{ if (lines > 0) { print; --lines; }} /^>/ { lines = 1}' | while read -r line; do echo $line > /dev/udp/localhost/6543; done
```

It's filtering out the first line and sending out just packets going in one direction (the /^>/).